# Processing: Multiple bullets in top down shooter

Tags: processing

I am trying to make a simple top down shooter. When the user presses W, A, S or D a 'bullet' (rectangle) will come out of the 'shooter'. With my code, you can only shoot one bullet per direction until it reaches the end of the screen. Is there a way to make it so they (the user) can shoot multiple bullets in one direction?

Here's my code:

```java
    package topdownshooter;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;


public class TopDownShooter extends PApplet {

    PImage shooter;
    float shooterX = 400;
    float shooterY = 300;

    float u_bulletSpeed;
    float l_bulletSpeed;
    float d_bulletSpeed;
    float r_bulletSpeed;

    boolean shootUp = false;
    boolean shootLeft = false;
    boolean shootDown = false;
    boolean shootRight = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("topdownshooter.TopDownShooter");
    }

    public void setup() {
        shooter = loadImage("shooter.png");
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(800, 600);
    }

    public void keyPressed() {
        if(key == 'w') {
            shootUp = true;
        }
        if(key == 'a') {
            shootLeft = true;
        }
        if(key == 's') {
            shootDown = true;
        }
        if(key == 'd') {
            shootRight = true;
        }
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(206);
        imageMode(CENTER);
        image(shooter, shooterX, shooterY);

        if(shootUp == true) {
            rect(shooterX, shooterY-u_bulletSpeed, 5, 5);
            u_bulletSpeed += 2;
            if(u_bulletSpeed > 300) {
                u_bulletSpeed = 0;
                shootUp = false;
            }

        }
        if(shootLeft == true) {
            rect(shooterX-l_bulletSpeed, shooterY, 5, 5);
            l_bulletSpeed += 2;
            if(l_bulletSpeed > 400) {
                l_bulletSpeed = 0;
                shootLeft = false;
            }
        }
        if(shootDown == true) {
            rect(shooterX, shooterY+d_bulletSpeed, 5, 5);
            d_bulletSpeed += 2;
            if(d_bulletSpeed > 300) {
                d_bulletSpeed = 0;
                shootDown = false;
            }
        }
        if(shootRight == true) {
            rect(shooterX+r_bulletSpeed, shooterY, 5, 5);
            r_bulletSpeed += 2;
            if(r_bulletSpeed > 400) {
                r_bulletSpeed = 0;
                shootRight = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The language is processing and I am using the eclipse IDE.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do if I were you. First I'd encapsulate your bullet data into a class, like this:

```
class Bullet{
  float x;
  float y;
  float xSpeed;
  float ySpeed;

  // you probably want a constructor here

  void drawBullet(){
    // bullet drawing code
  }
}
```

Then I'd create an `ArrayList` that holds `Bullet` instances:

```
ArrayList<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
```

To add a bullet, I'd create a new instance and add it to the `ArrayList` like this:

```
bullets.add(new Bullet(bulletX, bulletY));
```

Then to draw the bullets, I'd iterate over the `ArrayList` and call the corresponding function:

```
for(Bullet b : bullets){
  b.drawBullet();
}
```

Shameless self-promotion:

- [Here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) is a tutorial on creating classes.
- [Here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arraylists) is a tutorial on using `ArrayLists`.

Comment: @Hedgy Which part are you confused about? Also note that you could start by storing the values in separate arrays or ArrayLists. It's not a great habit to get into but it might help you get unstuck.

Comment: Everything works... almost. In the `bullets.add(new Bullet(bulletX, bulletY))`, i get the error `The variable bulletX/Y does not exist`. Ive tried making them variables, but then it says `The constructor Bullet(float, float) does not exist`

Comment: @Hedgy Please note that my code is just an example, and was not meant to be copy-pasted. Notice the comment in my `Bullet` class that says you'll probably want to add your own constructor.